# При запуске программы тут же выходит из нее и перекидывает к файлу с классом с ошибкой

Tags: swift, xcode, mac

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var numberFromScreen: Double = 0;
var firstNum: Double = 0;
var operation: Int = 0;
var mathSign: Bool = false;
@IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!


@IBAction func digits(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if mathSign == true {
        result.text = String(sender.tag)
        mathSign = false
    } else {
        result.text = result.text! + String(sender.tag)
    }
    numberFromScreen = Double(result.text!)!
}
func buttons(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if result.text != "" && sender.tag != 10 && sender.tag != 15 {
            firstNum = Double(result.text!)!
        

        if sender.tag == 11 {
            result.text = "/"
        }else if sender.tag == 12 {
            result.text = "*"
        } else if sender.tag == 13 {
            result.text = "-"
        } else if sender.tag == 14 {
            result.text = "+"
            

        operation = Int(sender.tag)
        mathSign = true;
        } else if sender.tag == 15 {
            if operation == 11 {
                result.text = String(firstNum / numberFromScreen)
            } else if sender.tag == 12 {
                result.text = String(firstNum * numberFromScreen)
            }else if sender.tag == 13 {
                result.text = String(firstNum - numberFromScreen)
            }else if sender.tag == 14 {
            result.text = String(firstNum + numberFromScreen)
        }
        } else if sender.tag == 10 {
            result.text = ""
            firstNum = 0
            numberFromScreen = 0
            operation = 0
        }
}
//    override func viewDidLoad() {
//        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//    }
    }
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Я конечно новичек, но что у вас делает класс в классе? О_о

Comment: И по поводу ошибки, если у вас сториборд, проверьте на предмет мертвых связей между кнопками и экшенами/аутлетами.

Comment: Скорее всего потерялся @IBAction в func buttons. Ну и ошибка говорит, что не может найти этот селектор.